# Select based on another select using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have one `select option` which is based on another `select option`.

Meaning,
If Option: **One** is selected from the first option then the second option should have Options: **S1, F1**.

If Option: **Two** is selected from the first option then the second option should have Options: **S2, F2**.

And So on..

But my **second** `select option` is having all the options.

**Note: Options in select are based on the database.**

I tried:

```
<td><select class="country" name="item1">
  <option value="Select Item">Item</option>
  <?php
  $stmt = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM item ORDER BY Sr ASC ');
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {

        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            extract($row);
            ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $IRN ?>"><?php echo $Name; ?></option>
  <?php
        }
    }

        ?>
</select></td>

      <td><select class="country" name="service1">
  <option value="Select Service">Service</option>
  <?php
  $stmt = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM service WHERE IRN = :irn ORDER BY Sr ASC ');
    $stmt->bindParam(':irn',$IRN);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {

        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            extract($row);
            ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $SRN ?>"><?php echo $Name; ?></option>
  <?php
        }
    }

        ?>
</select></td>
```

Focused Code:

```
  $stmt = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM service WHERE IRN = :irn ORDER BY Sr ASC ');
    $stmt->bindParam(':irn',$IRN);
    $stmt->execute();
```

**I know how to do this with fixed values (not using database & codding all options), but I am unable to do with dynamic values (using database for options).**

Comment: If I well understand your need, you must use a totally different way. A possible solution: 1) The first Items query, generating the corresponding `<select>`; 2) On user selection, Ajax to ask the server for Services matching the selected Item, returning the corresponding second `<select>`.

Comment: @cFreed Ok, So how to do that? Can you please explain it by adding/editing my codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example of simple chained select menus ought to gie you an idea how you can accomplish your goals - you would need to study this and implement database calls but to test you can copy the entire piece of code, save to

```
<?php
    /*
        Include other PHP files/libraries,
        set the session etc etc

        .....
    */


    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['action'], $_POST['id'] ) && $_POST['action']=='get_dependant_menu' ){
        ob_clean();

        $action=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'action', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        $id=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

        if( $action && $id && !is_nan( $id ) ){
            /*

                In production you would use the supplied POST values to query the database
                and process the recordset - sending back the results as formatted HTML to
                the AJAX callback function. 

                For the sake of demonstration though the script simply sends back data from a
                simple loop...

                sql=select * from table where id=? etc

            */



            for( $i=1; $i <= 10; $i++ )echo "<option value='Service-$id-$i'>Service-$id-$i";
        }
        exit();
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dependent / Chained SELECT menus</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
            /* Basic Ajax function */
            function ajax(m,u,p,c,o){
                /*
                    m=Method,
                    u=Url,
                    p=Params,
                    c=Callback,
                    o=Options
                */
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 )c.call( this, xhr.response, o, xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() );
                };

                var params=[];
                for( var n in p )params.push(n+'='+p[n]);

                switch( m.toLowerCase() ){
                    case 'post': p=params.join('&'); break;
                    case 'get': u+='?'+params.join('&'); p=null; break;
                }

                xhr.open( m.toUpperCase(), u, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send( p );
            }


            /* Callback function to populate second menu */
            function createmenu(r,o,h){
                /*
                    r=response
                    o=options ( sent by ajax function )
                    h=response headers
                */
                o.menu.innerHTML=r;
            }



            function bindEvents(){
                /* Get references to the two dropdown menus */
                var oSelItem=document.querySelector('select[name="item1"]');
                var oSelService=document.querySelector('select[name="service1"]');


                /* Assign an `onchange` event listener */
                oSelItem.onchange=function(e){

                    var method='post';
                    var url=location.href;

                    /* the parameters to send to the PHP script */
                    var params={
                        'action':'get_dependant_menu',
                        'id':this.options[ this.options.selectedIndex ].value
                    };

                    /* Options to pass to the ajax callback */
                    var opts={
                        menu:oSelService
                    };

                    /* make the ajax request */
                    ajax.call( this, method, url, params, createmenu, opts );

                }.bind( oSelItem );
            }

            document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', bindEvents,false );
        </script>

        <style type='text/css' charset='utf-8'>
            select {padding:1rem;width:300px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Chained select menus using basic ajax</h1>
        <form method='post'>

            <select name='item1' class='country'>
                <?php
                    /*
                        In production your code would use a database call
                        to populate the menu but for example purposes it
                        simply uses a loop
                    */

                    for( $i=1; $i <= 10; $i++ )echo "<option value=$i>Item $i";

                ?>
            </select>

            <select name='service1' class='country'>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know why you were unable or unwilling to attempt to implement the above AJAX solution with your own database code but after your persistant pleading perhaps the following will give you a better idea. This has NOT been tested!

```
<?php


    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['action'], $_POST['id'] ) && $_POST['action']=='get_dependant_menu' ){
        ob_clean();

        $action=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'action', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        $id=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

        if( $action && $id && !empty( $id ) ){

            $sql='select * from service where irn = :irn order by sr asc';
            $stmt->bindParam(':irn',$id);
            $stmt->execute();

            if( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 ){
                 while( $row=$stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){
                    echo "<option value='{$row['IRN']}'>{$row['Name']}";
                 }
            }
        }
        exit();
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dependent / Chained SELECT menus</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
            function ajax(m,u,p,c,o){
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 )c.call( this, xhr.response, o, xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() );
                };

                var params=[];
                for( var n in p )params.push(n+'='+p[n]);

                switch( m.toLowerCase() ){
                    case 'post': p=params.join('&'); break;
                    case 'get': u+='?'+params.join('&'); p=null; break;
                }

                xhr.open( m.toUpperCase(), u, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send( p );
            }
            function createmenu(r,o,h){
                o.menu.innerHTML=r;
            }



            function bindEvents(){
                var oSelItem=document.querySelector('select[name="item1"]');
                var oSelService=document.querySelector('select[name="service1"]');
                oSelItem.onchange=function(e){

                    var method='post';
                    var url=location.href;
                    var params={
                        'action':'get_dependant_menu',
                        'id':this.options[ this.options.selectedIndex ].value
                    };
                    var opts={
                        menu:oSelService
                    };
                    ajax.call( this, method, url, params, createmenu, opts );
                }.bind( oSelItem );
            }
            document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', bindEvents,false );
        </script>
        <style type='text/css' charset='utf-8'>
            select {padding:1rem;width:300px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Chained select menus using basic ajax</h1>
        <form method='post'>

            <select name='item1' class='country'>
            <?php

                $sql='select * from `item` order by `sr` asc;';
                $stmt=$user_home->runQuery( $sql );
                $stmt->execute();

                if( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 ){
                    while( $row=$stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){
                        echo "<option value='{$row['IRN']}'>{$row['Name']}";
                    }
                }

            ?>
            </select>
            <select name='service1' class='country'>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When a new row is added using the `Add Row` button the onchange event handlers registed above in the `bindEvents` function will NOT be cloned with the newly added select menu. To ensure that any & all newly added select menus use the same mechanism ( ie: ajax ) then the easiest to implement solution is to assign `inline event handlers` to the `item` dropdown menu. The javascript above can be changed to ( not tested btw )

```
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
    /* AJAX FUNCTION */
    function ajax(m,u,p,c,o){
        var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 )c.call( this, xhr.response, o, xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() );
        };

        var params=[];
        for( var n in p )params.push(n+'='+p[n]);

        switch( m.toLowerCase() ){
            case 'post': p=params.join('&'); break;
            case 'get': u+='?'+params.join('&'); p=null; break;
        }

        xhr.open( m.toUpperCase(), u, true );
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.send( p );
    }


    /* AJAX CALLBACK */
    function createmenu(r,o,h){
        o.menu.innerHTML=r;
    }

    /* INLINE EVENT HANDLER */
    function evtselect(e){
        try{
            var el=e.target;
            /* it is NOT necessary to have the `action` parameter... that was for testing for me initially */
            var params={
                'action':'get_dependant_menu',
                'id':el.value
            };

            /* 

                newly added nodes ( add row ) should have their names changed*/
                so the following line needs attention! Basically you need to find, in the DOM, 
                the next select menu on the same row ( think parentNode, nextSibling etc etc )

                The following is NOT tested......!!!!!
            */
            var td=el.parentNode.nextSibling;

            var opts={
                menu:td.querySelector('select')
            };
            ajax.call( this, method, url, params, createmenu, opts );
        }catch( err ){
            console.log( err );
        }
    }
</script>
```

To use the `inline event handler` you would typically do:

```
<select name='item' onchange='evtselect(event)'>/* options */</select>
```

Comment: Ok, so I  should use this code, can you please edit the codes as per my codes.

Comment: Did you try running the above code at all? The mechanism is in place to populate secondary dropdown based upon selection from first dropdown but you need to replace the static loops with your database code - it should be straightforward enough

Comment: I am in lots of confusing, so I request you to please update it with my codes. Then it will be easy for me to understand what I did, and what it should be done. Please a request

Comment: Sir, Please help me. I request you.

Comment: Sir, I will be thankful if you update your answer with my codes!

Comment: We are here to answer question of each other, not to do each others work. If you want to do something like this i recommend do some research about ajax and jQuery. It's no rockets science and basically base knowledge for any web developer.

Comment: @RamRaider Tried your code but it is not working. There are no options in service selection after/before selecting item option.

Comment: does the `country` dropdown get populated? Are there errors in the PHP error log? Can you see the ajax request in the console? Does the ajax request return anything as a response?

Comment: The `item1` `select option` shows the `options`, but `service1` do not show any `options`, even after selecting `item1`.

Comment: @RamRaider You mean I should press `f12` in the browser and a console tab is shown. should I take ss of that?

Comment: yes: look at the network tab to see what is happening with the ajax request. Look closely at the parameters sent and any response

Comment: it is the XHR requests that you should be interested in.... you need to study this carefully, it is very hard trying to do this remotely like this... Please take time to analyse what is going on with this. The 2st dropdown menu is populated at page load by the database. When there is a `change` event on that dropdown it fires an ajax request. OK so far? That AJAX request queries the PHP script to run the sql query that is used to populate the 2nd dropdown. OK? Look at the XHR request in detail and report back

Comment: so, open the console. clear the console. Then use the 1st select and choose a new option from the menu. LOOK at the request and response

Comment: @RamRaider I tried to do as you said, have a look at new [screenshot](https://imgur.com/oJugCG1). If it is difficult to check, should I upload to the web and provide you link?

Comment: @RamRaider I have uploaded the code online please have a look at this [link](http://whspr.epizy.com/chirag/new_invoice.php)

Comment: OK - so the AJAX request is working fine and sending an ID value of `ZZ2017TF11A2` ~ please show me the PHP code that you are using to process the ajax request. Is it the same as the code I added??

Comment: looking at the php code I provided to process the ajax request it was expecting the ID value to be an integer rather than a long string such as `ZZ2017TF11A2` ~ have altered the last piece of code (php section at top ) slightly if you look closely.

Comment: @RamRaider Yes, the code you provided is same. And I got the bug. It was because of `$id=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );` at 4th line of your code, it should be `$id=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );`. I just found the bug. **One more why the selected options is not shown?**

Comment: @RamRaider [Updated Link](http://whspr.epizy.com/chirag/new_invoice.php).

Comment: If the `Add Row` button `clones` the previous row then you will need to change the javascript code and use `inline event handlers` attached to the `select` menu as `cloneNode` does NOT clone event handlers that are not assigned inline afaik

Comment: OOps, what are you saying, I am not able to understand? Is the above information is about,  adding more rows with select options....? **And why the selected option is not been shown? How to fix it?**

Comment: to be fair fella I do have things to do. The 2nd ajax menu is now being populated with data based upon the selection made in the 1st dropdown. That is the main issue fixed!

Comment: OK; Thanks a lot for giving your valuable time for me but, while upgrading to your code, **the selected option is not shown**

Comment: but the menu IS populated... surely you can figure out how to make an item `selected` - if this has helped please mark the answer as correct etc etc

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time!

Comment: If there is only 1 option in the 2nd dropdown you would add an attribute to the html `selected` - ie: `<option value='X' selected>Y</option>` ~ good luck with the rest - it is fairly straightforward but if/when you get stuck ask a new question and no doubt you will get help

Comment: I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47321918/select-based-on-another-select-using-php-not-working) with reference to this code. As you know what I am trying to do, the new question will be easy for you to understand and answer. Thank You